# Can't use Symfony console Warning: DOMElement::setAttribute(): string is not in UTF-8

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8, console

I had a work for my school where I had to code with symfony 
I did my thing and posted it on my git

https://github.com/Maltiize/exosymfony

But after doing a clone on my laptop
but I noticed that git didn't take in account some of the files in /vendor
so i removed the vendor folder and did a

> composer install

to reset everything

But right now Im stuck with this error.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]   Warning:
>   DOMElement::setAttribute(): string is not in UTF-8

Searched every where didn't find anything

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try an `php app/console cache:clear -vvv` and read the logs if you find something weird ?

Comment: BTW I cloned your project, removed the vendor folder with `rm -rf vendor/` and re-install all project dependencies with `composer install` then everything are working well

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems it was because my project wasn't in the good directory or something 
I recently changed from mamp to wamp ( win10) 
My git repo was in the mamp directory but when i changed to the mamp's one it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (but on ubuntu 16). Finally i found out that my system charset was ISO. I changed it to UTF-8 by using

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```